# Right use of the .dll file?

Tags: dll, coreldraw

I need to use the Corel Photo-Paint so I already installed it in my PC.
When I wanted to run the program I get the error:

```
This programme can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing . Try to reinstall this.
```

So, I download the .dll file and then I copied in the path:

```
C:\Windows\System32
```

Now I get this:

```
The entry point procedure ucrtbase.terminate not found in the dynamic link library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
```

How can I fix this problem and finally use the program?

*This is not about programming but I don't know how to use this forum correctly.

Comment: Try heading over to http://superuser.com/. They are in the same community of forums, and they focus more on general computer questions.

Comment: Dll files are part of programs which are in files for themselves, such that they can be shared by multiple programs. It seems your program expects an other copy of the DLL, than the one you provided.

Comment: but where could I make the other copy?, I mean which path? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I believe you copied it to the fight path, the alternative being next to the program '.exe' file. The version of the DLL file seems wrong however.

Comment: Did you use the installer that draw comes with?  It should install the crt components you need.

Comment: Yeah! I did it, but does not work. I think it's something with my PC because I format it just a few months ago. But I don't know how to know what is my PC missing.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have the **ucrtbase.dll** on your system?

if you don't, you can download it here:
http://www.opendll.com/index.php?file-download=ucrtbase.dll&arch=64bit&version=10.0.10137.0&dsc=Microsoft?-C-Runtime-Library

Then extract it in **c:\windows\SysWOW64** folder

Try again

Comment: I tried what you said but didn't work. Thanks anyway

Comment: Check if your system is up-to-date. Source: [Microsoft Forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/the-procedure-entry-point-ucrtbaseterminate-could/e45c2162-bb43-4082-a3dd-d715c7ea1f46?auth=1)